# Yii2 ActiveRecord - default condition causes sql error

Tags: mysql, activerecord, yii2

I'm working on a project where I have my own ActiveRecord class that extends `\yii\db\ActiveRecord`:

```
class ActiveRecord extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{   
    const DELETED_STATUS = 1;

    /**
     *  Defines the soft delete field
     */
    public static function softDeleteField()
    {
        return 'Deleted';
    }

    /**
     *  Overrides the find() function to add sensitivity to deletes
     */
    public static function find()
    {
        return parent::find()->where(['not',[
            static::softDeleteField() => static::DELETED_STATUS
        ]]);
    }
}
```

I wanted to be able to make everything soft-deleteable. According to the [documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-activerecord.html#find%28%29-detail), applying a default condition like this should be doable.

It's working great for the most part, but when I try to do a join then I get a sql error. An example of this is:

```
$query = Model::find(); // ActiveRecord of table1

$query->joinWith(['alias' => function($query) { $query->from(['alias' => 'table2']); }]);
```

And I get the error:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'Deleted' in where clause is ambiguous
The SQL being executed was: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `table1` LEFT JOIN `table2` `alias` ON `table1`.`StatusID` = `alias`.`StatusID` WHERE (NOT (`Deleted`=1)) AND (NOT (`Deleted`=1))
```

I *was* able to get this to work by changing my join query to

```
// Omitting the alias in the from() method
$query->joinWith(['alias' => function($query) { $query->from('table2'); }]);
```

and changing my `find()` method to

```
public static function find()
{
    return parent::find()->where(['not',[
        static::tableName()."."static::softDeleteField() => static::DELETED_STATUS
    ]]);
}
```

But this will only work if there are no aliases. Is there something I can do to make this work for join queries with aliases as well?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `SELF` and not `static`

like this

```
public static function find()
{
    return parent::find()->where(['not',[
        SELF::softDeleteField() => SELF::DELETED_STATUS
    ]]);
}
```

Comment: I could do that, but occasionally the field that indicates whether something is deleted is different in the class that extends my `ActiveRecord` class, so I need to use late-static binding.

Answer (score 0):

Error message says: many table has Deleted fields, you have to clarify what field do use in your sql query.

You have to define `Deleted` with table name or alias like that

```
/**
 *  Defines the soft delete field
 */
public static function softDeleteField()
{
    return self::tableName() . '.Deleted';
}
```

Comment: Do you know of a way to programmatically determine if the table is being aliased or not? As you can see in my original question, I am using the `tableName()` method for now, but this does not work if a table is aliased in a join query.

Comment: @spencer4of6, I think you may not use aliases in Yii2, because it's not useful with it's ActiveQuery and SQL builder